# How to update Propel Classes after updating the Database in Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony-1.4, propel

I'm using a Test Database on my Localhost!

For further Tests Scenarios i dumped the Live Database(with new Tables and many more data) and i imported it in my localhost Database.

Now i have some Errors, of cause, some new tables don't exist in my propel classes!

should i update the schema.yml (there ist mille datas now into my database) before rebuild propel?

How can i now process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you should get errors if tables exist in your database but not in your schema. Are you sure you don't mean the other way around?

Anyway, your `schema.yml` should always be in sync with your database, so make sure you have all the necessary tables and columns defined in `schema.yml`, then verify your database contains them too (use `propel-build-sql` if needed) and finally do a `propel-build-sql` to make sure your model is up to date.